# how to check if a string includes all array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

how to check if a string includes all array elements, regardless of element's position inside the string

for example:

```
var arr = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor'];
var str = 'lorem blue dolor sky ipsum';
```

I need something like this:

```
if(str.includesAll(arr)){console.log('string includes all elements');}
else{console.log('string does not include all elements');}
```

Comment: Here is one I wrote just for you https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3rdcezmg/ - it splits the sentence and checks each word in the sentences instead of the array item in the sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `Array.prototype.every` to call your check function on every element.

```js
var arr = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor'];
var str = 'lorem blue dolor sky ipsum';

console.log(arr.every(el => str.includes(el)));
```

Comment: problem - if str is for example - `sky loremdoloripsum blue`. I need to check only word by word